# IntelliJ Kotlin - How do I fix "Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library" in a project?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I've been trying to set up a new Kotlin project in IntelliJ IDEA, using the default IntelliJ Build System (not Gradle) and JDK 15. Whenever it creates the default main.kt file, and I try to build and run the main function, which looks like this:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

the build fails after a short time with the following errors:

> Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Array'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library

> Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library

and

> Kotlin: Unresolved reference: println

I've tried changing the project SDK to the kotlin SDK, to Java 14 and to Java 1.8. I'm not sure exactly how to add the dependency it asks for. Any help is appreciated.

This is what the dependencies window shows within the project:
[image: Module Dependencies]

Right now the project is using JDK 15, and Kotlin 1.4.10. I've tried updating the plugin, uninstalling and reinstalling, deactivating and reactivating, all to no avail.

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies" tab.

Comment: Please provide more information as @bedrov's written

Comment: Project configuration looks fine. Could you please attach your project to check IDE generated files?

Comment: @y.bedrov Project files have been added, thanks

Comment: Please try to remove ".idea/libraries" file and reimport project again.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you for the help @y.bedrov!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing the .idea/library file inside the project directory and then selecting "use library from plugin" when prompted to configure Kotlin files by the IDE solved the problem.

Comment: 1) close project 2) delete `*.iml` and whole `.idea` directory 3) open the project again

Answer (score 38):

Try enabling `KotlinJavaRuntime`

1. Open `Project Structure` window (File > Project Structure)
2. Go into `Modules`
3. Go to `Dependencies` tab
4. Tick the `Enable KotlinJavaRuntime` checkbox

Comment: I do not have such a checkbox `Enable KotlinJavaRuntime`.

Answer (score 4):

Please provide more information and check what Kotlin version do you have installed:

1. Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates: install the latest version of Kotlin
2. File > Project Structure > Project: what is your Project SDK there? Choose 15 (something line java version "15.0.1"). If you don't have 15 there, click "+" and add the newest version (unless you need an older version).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to add KotlinJavaRuntime library in you project. Please see paragraph "Create Kotlin files in Java projects" in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mixing-java-and-kotlin-in-one-project.html
After configuration you should see needed jars in **lib** folder in your project. Rebuild you project. Make also File->Invalidate Cache/Restart.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above but eventually found out, that in one project, my SDKs were completely broken after the newest Intellij Update. If you go to Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs, I had an entry for Kotlin with a non existing path for an Intellij Version of last year. This was definitely not there before and it seems to have messed up the kotlin installation. After i deleted that entry and as described above the libraries as well, it worked again.

Answer (score 2):

**Please note**: This can solve many problems, but also resets your project settings.

For me this helped:

1. Close the project
2. Delete *.idea* folder
3. Open project

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it was a misconfigured IntelliJ instance.

> Project Structure -> SDKs -> kotlinSDK -> + -> ok

rebuild will be work fine

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Kotlin Standard Library JDK extension was missing. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 with  IntelliJ 2020.3 newly installed. I run to the same issue here.

To solve this issue, I made a new kotlin file in my project. Then when the system was trying to add this new Kotlin file, you can find a notification related to "Configure project" on the right bottom corner of screen, click the notification. I get the following dialog.

Then check the Use library from plugin, this solve the issue.
[Use library from plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOaLv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can open files in folder ".idea" and see if there are closing tags `</tagName>` missing at the end of each file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `apply plugin: kotlin-android-extensions` was not added in **library's `build.gradle`** file.

Please check for each modules. Each module should have `apply plugin: kotlin-android-extensions`