# Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Int'

Tags: maven, kotlin

I'm trying to run a java/kotlin project, and i'm having trouble with the kotlin side of things.

Whenever i try to run my project I get the following error:

`Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Int'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library`

I tried following the steps mentioned here [IntelliJ Kotlin - How do I fix "Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library" in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906975/intellij-kotlin-how-do-i-fix-ensure-that-you-have-a-dependency-on-the-kotlin)

but it still doesn't work.

Anyone knows how I can possibly fix this?

Comment: Did you try running the project outside the IDE? Is the project built with Gradle? If so, could you share the gradle build file as well?

Comment: Just FYI the official documentation can help you create a Gradle/Maven/Ant project: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html